# Does Wamp server handle mutiple HTTP connections?

Tags: php, sql-server, multithreading, httprequest

I am creating an application on the phone that queries to the server. The server side scripting is done in PHP. Do i have to create threads to handle multiple http requests or does wamp provide for it. How does Wamp handle multiple HTTP requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAMP runs an instance of Apache. Apache can handle many HTTP requests. Your web application determines how those requests are handled.

Answer (score 0):

Apache does that for you. That's the point of having a HTTP Server (serving multiple clients).